# Error using Polynomials in Julia

Tags: julia, polynomials

I am trying to use polynomials for a code I have to run.

I updated all the packages and the package Polynomials is well added. 
But when trying `using Polynomials` I have the following error message :

> WARNING: Module Compat with uuid 12374366933959441 is missing from the cache.
>
> This may mean module Compat does not support precompilation but is imported by a module that does.
>
> ERROR: LoadError: Declaring **precompile**(false) is not allowed in files that are being precompiled.
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> [1] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:455
>
> [2] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
>
> [3] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
>
> [4] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
>
> [5] anonymous at ./:2
>
> while loading xxx/.julia/v0.6/Polynomials/src/Polynomials.jl, in expression starting on line 8
>
> ERROR: Failed to precompile Polynomials to xxx/.julia/lib/v0.6/Polynomials.ji.
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> [1] compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:710
>
> [2] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:497
>
> [3] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405

when asking `versioninfo()` I get the following :

> Julia Version 0.6.1
>
> Commit 0d7248e2ff (2017-10-24 22:15 UTC)
>
> Platform Info:
>
> OS: Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
>
> CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
>
> WORD_SIZE: 64
>
> BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
>
> LAPACK: libopenblas64_
>
> LIBM: libopenlibm
>
> LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)

Does anyone understand what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: First thing to try: quit Julia and have another go. I’ve seen this message twice today and it went away each time...

Comment: Sorry... indeed it works :/ ..